# What is the command to generate migration script from existing sequelize models?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I've created models using the following command.

`$ node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name XYZ --attributes "....."`

But by mistake I deleted the folder containing migration script. Now I want to generate this script again.
I tried using `sequelize migration:create`, but it generated any empty file.
Please Help.

Answer (score -2):

What you need to do now, after you generated a new migration file is to copy the skeleton from here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#skeleton and to customize your migration using the functions that you need.